# Getting data from HttpRequest (POST)

Tags: php, c++

i make http request (post) from a c++ applications to be recieved from a php script using wininet.

when i do something like this

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents(php://input)
$file = fopen("log.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$data);
?>
```

This works fine, but when i do something like this

```
<?php
    $buffer = $_POST['buffer'];
    $file = fopen("log2.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$buffer);
    fclose($file);  
?>
```

it just opens the log2.txt without writing any data to the file. i am wondering why, what seems to be the problem as it doesnt seem to show me any error from this end.

Comment: Have you tried printing $_POST['buffer'] with var_dump()?

Comment: Still the same problem, empty file nothing was saved

Comment: What is the buffer variable at runtime? if var_dump prints nothing, you have not set the POST var probaly

Comment: doesnt print a thing, if i try it the first way, it sends , the second, doesnt send anything